# how to handle errors in graphql mutations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm using graphql for the first time in a rails application and i want to handle model validation errors.

My implementation is as follows:

**Model code:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :phone_number, presence: true
end
```

**mutation_type.rb**

```
Types::MutationType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name "Mutation"

  field :createUser, Types::UserType do
    description 'Allows you to create a new user'

    argument :name, !types.String
    argument :phone_number, !types.String

    resolve ->(obj, args, ctx) {
      user = User.create!(args.to_h)
      user
    }
  end
end
```

**user_type.rb**

```
Types::UserType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'User'
  description 'Represents a user'

  field :id, !types.Int, 'The ID of a user'

  field :name, !types.String, 'The name of the user'

  field :phone_number, !types.String, 'The phone number of a user'

  field :errors, types[types.String], "Reasons the object couldn't be created or updated" do
    resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) { obj.errors.full_messages }
  end

end
```

Now in `graphiql`, when i try to create a user with invalid entry. It does not show the `errors` in the error field i have added in the `user_type` and it shows this

```
{
  "status": 422,
  "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
  "exception": "#<ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Phone number can't be blank>",
  "traces": {
    "Application Trace": [
      {
        "id": 15,
        "trace": "app/graphql/types/mutation_type.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'"
      },
      {
....
```

Can someone suggest me what am I doing wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i have changed the mutation file and used `begin and rescue` block to handle the errors and used save! to handle the errors:

```
Types::MutationType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name "Mutation"

  field :createUser, Types::UserType do
    description 'Allows you to create a new user'

    argument :name, !types.String
    argument :phone_number, !types.String

    resolve ->(obj, args, ctx) {
      begin
        user = User.new(args.to_h)
        user.save!
        user
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => err
        GraphQL::ExecutionError.new("#{user.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}")
      end
    }
  end
end
```

With this setup, i now have this response

```
{
  "data": {
    "createUser": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Phone number can't be blank",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createUser"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is quite detailed and can be used on the frontend easily.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation few days ago. IMO its better to separate errors attribute wise so that you can display errors appropriately in the frontend. So I created a generic ErrorType and used at several places.

> ErrorType

```
ErrorType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name "GenericErrormessage"
  description "Displays field wise errors "

  field :field_name do
    type !types.String
    resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) do
      obj[0].to_s.split('.')[-1]
    end
  end

  field :field_errors do
    type types[types.String]
    resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) do
      obj[-1]
    end
  end

end
```

And used it like this.

```
field :errors do
  type types[ErrorType]
    resolve ->(obj, args, ctx) {
      obj.errors.messages
    }
  end
end
```

If errors field length is greater than 0. it means object creation is failed and corresponding errors can be displayed. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Still not working for me !! Can you please show the mutation_type.rb file here ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the method create without a bang?

`User.create(args.to_h)` instead of `User.create!(args.to_h)`

The create! method throws an exception

Comment: Ok. That dint work for me but with `create!` helped me with another way. I'll write in my answer